# Gradle exec commandLine does not work as expected

Tags: macos, gradle, command-line

I'm currently working on a Gradle project in OSX
My function in a .gradle file looks like this

```
ext.MyFunction = {

     def fastlaneCommand = [
             'fastlane',
             '-version'
     ]

     def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

     exec {
         ignoreExitValue true
         standardOutput stdout
         workingDir PathsModel.instance.GetDeployerRoot()
         commandLine fastlaneCommand
         LOG.WARN("YOUR CLI COMMAND: " + commandLine)
     }
     println "Output:\n$stdout"
}
```

And then in 'build.gradle'

```
task jenkins_deploy() {
    doFirst {
        MyFunction()
    }
}
```

When it comes time for commandLine to be executed
This outputs:

```
W A R N I N G:  YOUR CLI COMMAND: [fastlane, -version]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jenkins_deploy'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'fastlane''
```

I know for a fact that fastlane is in my path as '$HOME/.fastlane/bin' which is where the executable is located. And if I simply open Terminal and type

> 'fastlane -version'

from any directory, fastlane tools start-up and do what they're supposed to be doing.

I suppose my question is:
What are the possible differences between me opening a terminal and inputting the command manually, and me asking Gradle to do the exact same thing using 'exec'? 
Am I misunderstanding what 'exec' and 'commandLine' actually do?

Some info on 'fastlane' is that it's using Ruby, which i don't know a lot about. This may prove relevant.

EDIT: I *have* attempted 'version' the 2nd element in the fastlaneCommand array, as both 'version' and '-version'

EDIT 2 (ACTUAL SOLUTION): Although the marked answer below is a definite workaround, the solution [Actual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403573/specify-path-environment-does-not-work-when-running-gradle-exec) has the full reason as to why this happens and why it works.

Comment: I suppose it should be: `['sh', 'fastlane', '-version']`.

Comment: @Opal Excellent, as that's helped me get past this part of the execution :)
However, I don't have to include 'sh' in the terminal. Would you also happen to know why this might be?

Comment: Also if you'd like to make that comment an Answer, I can mark it as correct. (Unless something more explanatory comes along)

Comment: Have not the link under my arm, but if you omit `sh` it would be executed as a script located in current directory (or configured as the second argument). If you prefix it with `sh` it will be executed with shell and $PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

I suppose it should be:

```
['sh', 'fastlane', '-version']
```

**Explanation**:

Have not the link under my arm, but if you omit `sh` it would be executed as a script located in current directory (or directory configured as the second argument). If you prefix it with `sh` it will be executed with shell and $PATH variable.