# Discrepancy building project in Android Studio vs Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a complex Android project consisting of multiple Java and C++ modules and using several build tools (e.g. CMake, swig). The project builds just fine when built from the command line using `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` but fails to build when built from Android Studio. I cleaned, invalidated caches, synced, etc to no avail.

Important to note: this project builds fine in Android Studio too on other systems like Ubuntu (17.* and 18.*) but fails on MacOS (10.13 but also earlier if I remember correctly).

Here is the error reported by Android Studio:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':IndoorsLocator:runSwig'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'swig''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:198)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:329)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'swig'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "swig" (in directory "/Users/tom/workspace/indoors-scripts/setup-scripts/workspace-android/IndoorsAndroid/IndoorsLocator"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 8 more
```

[image: build failing in Android Studio]

On the command line:
[image: build going through via command line (note we are passed "IndoorsLocator:runSwig" already)]

Here is what the definition of "runSwig"-task looks like:

```
task runSwig(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'swig'

    doFirst {
        coreWrapperDir.mkdirs()
    }

    def swigFileCore = "${projectDir}/src/" + "swig.i"
    def headerFiles = "${projectDir}/include"
    def swigWrapFile = 'src/swig_wrap.cxx'

    inputs.file swigFileCore
    inputs.dir headerFiles
    outputs.dir coreWrapperDir.absolutePath
    outputs.file swigWrapFile

    // this write the generated swig C++ file to "${projectDir}/src"
    args '-c++', '-java', '-package', javaPackage, '-noexcept', '-outdir', coreWrapperDir.absolutePath, "-I${headerFiles}", '-o', swigWrapFile, swigFileCore
}
```

The log indicates that Android Studio is looking for swig in the current working directory instead of looking it up inside $PATH, but I am clueless about how to tell Android Studio where to look instead. Any ideas?

```
Cannot run program "swig" (in directory "/Users/tom/workspace/indoors-scripts/setup-scripts/workspace-android/IndoorsAndroid/IndoorsLocator")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403573/specify-path-environment-does-not-work-when-running-gradle-exec checked this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is due to a "bug" in OSX: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5631#issuecomment-401775152

I did not find a way to easily fix it for the latest version of OSX (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks) but worked around it by hardcoding the path in build.gradle:

```
task runSwig(type: Exec) {
    // workaround for OSX, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51383822/198996
    File testFile = new File('/usr/local/bin/swig');
    if (testFile.isFile()) {
        commandLine '/usr/local/bin/swig'
    } else {
        commandLine 'swig'
    }
}
```

That's an awful workaround if you ask me, so I would be happy to award the bounty to whoever comes up with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a need for some debugging to get more info about the problem. Add the code below to your `build.gradle` file of `IndoorsLocator` module and run it again. This should print the path environment variable and also run a java command which I'm assuming is also within the path. Then perform a gradle sync and compile or run the code. Open the build window as in your first image and when the build stops, find the `testPath` within the `Run tasks` list and share it's output. Or more preferably, switch the `Build` to text view as in the image below and share the complete log. Testing it from the command would also help to make sure that it's running as expected.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { addedTask ->
    if (addedTask.name.startsWith("preDebugBuild")) {
        addedTask.dependsOn 'testPath'
    }
}

task testPath {
    mustRunBefore 'checkDebugManifest'
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'echo', '$PATH'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'java', '-version'
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

## Update 1

Based on your first comment, this is a weird outcome! Java is supposed to be in the path, so $PATH must've been set somehow yet `echo $PATH` didn't work. Updated the code to further go down the rabbit hole.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { addedTask ->
    if (addedTask.name.startsWith("preDebugBuild")) {
        addedTask.dependsOn 'testPath'
    }
}

task testPath {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'printenv'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'which', 'java'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'which', 'swig'
        }
    }
}
```

PS: my mistake on the `mustRunBefore`, it doesn't exist and I added it accident!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about switching to text view for the Build-panel! That's really useful.

I had to remove the line starting with "mustRunBefore" - I think it's because we are forced to use an old version of gradle plugin. This is the output without that line:
`:IndoorsLocator:testPath
$PATH
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)`

Seems like he is not evaluating the $PATH variable at all?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far, you did a great job helping me to investigate this issue! I found the root cause (OSX bug) and decided to workaround it since there does not seem to be a clean solution as I had hoped for. (see my answer below)

Comment: That's great, I still have a solution in mind which I hope is clean but need the result from my last code update to make sure

Comment: There you go: https://pastebin.com/TMm0g1PE - `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.DWsBI8UTnd/Listeners
SHELL=/bin/bash
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HqXv61LKKS/Render
LOGNAME=tom
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.google.android.studio.6548
USER=tom
HOME=/Users/tom
TMPDIR=/var/folders/3l/j87th09j2jzdpbg_96w2kcd80000gn/T/
/usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this line in your build.gradle?

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn runSwig
}
```

Anyway you can refer to this github's project that uses swig: https://github.com/sureshjoshi/android-ndk-swig-example

Comment: `runSwig` is being executed already as shown in the images, hence it 's dependency is already made and is not the problem

Comment: Right, as mentioned by @ahasbini the task is being executed just fine. As I've said before, it does work on other platforms (i.e. Linux). Thanks for the link to ndk-swig, that is our last option I guess if nobody can help me fix the current issue.